# BigDecimal and Double digit limit?

Tags: java, string, floating-point, precision, bigdecimal

I am making a phi (golden ratio) calculator, and I'm having an issue with the precision of the answers I get.
I realized that there seems to be a fixed number of digits that my answers can be up to, and afterwards it just truncates. At first I thought it was an issue with doubles, so I changed to BigDecimals. Yet the problem still persists.

Here was my original double logic:

```
public static final double PHI = 1.6180339887498948482045;

b = Double.parseDouble(field.getText());
a = b * PHI;
aPlusB = a + b;

System.out.println(a.toString());
```

Here's the code for my BigDecimal Logic:

```
public static final double PHI = 1.6180339887498948482045;

BigDecimal phi = new BigDecimal(calculationHolder.PHI);
MathContext context = new MathContext(15, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(BigInteger.ZERO);         
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(BigInteger.ZERO);            
BigDecimal aPlusB = new BigDecimal(BigInteger.ZERO);

b = new BigDecimal(field.getText());
a = b.multiply(phi, context);
aPlusB = a.add(b, context);

System.out.println(a.toString());
```

Now if I were to make b = 1:

my double logic would return 1.618033988749895(many digits short of the real value it should be).

If I were to use my BigDecimal logic, it would return 1.61803398874989 (even less precise)

If I were to use a really large number like 123456789123456 for b,

My double logic would return 199757280943680.16, and by BigDecimal logic returns 199757280943680 (even less precise, and not even any decimals).

I'm confused about this behavior. It seems like, if anything, the BigDecimal logic is giving me even less precise answers, and I don't know why.

Could anyone please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specified 15 decimal digits of precision here:

```
new MathContext(15, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

You got 15 decimal digits of precision here:

```
1.61803398874989
```

You got exactly what you asked for. Do you understand what the [first constructor parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/MathContext.html#MathContext-int-java.math.RoundingMode-) does?

Comment: Isn't that 14 decimal places? Or does it start counting from the radix point? Even if that's the case, why does the BigDecimal stop giving that precision with larger number inputs?

Comment: Or by decimal digits did the documentation mean digits in general? I was under the impression that they meant decimal places. My bad, I'll test that out.

Comment: @MainManAndy: You should perhaps read more about the difference between ***scale*** (number of decimal *places* -- more or less the number of digits *right of the decimal dot*) and ***precision*** (total number of digits - decimal digits, because BigDecimal does not support any other digits than 0..9).

Comment: @MainManAndy: `199757280943680` is also 15 digits. You specified you didn't want more than 15 digits, so that is what you got.

Comment: It means 'significant digits', i.e. *all* the digits. It isn't the same thing as 'decimal places'.